# where is log file of Gnome 3?

Tags: opensuse, gnome3

I've just installed gnome3 on openSUSE 11.4 following [these instructions](http://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE%3aGNOME_3.0) but when from `kdm` I try to load gnome3, it just shows me a page saying that it cannot load and it doesn't give me any further information about what is the problem. Where should I look for log file that stores error messages?

Comment: I read your comment on Caleb answer that you successfully find it, could you write answer & accept it after 48h.

Answer (score 5):

Try `/var/log/X.*`. There are usually several logs to do with X there, one for the login manager and one for each session started up as well as the previous session.

Comment: there is no `X.*` file, but i found what i was looking for in `/var/log/messages` file. thanx ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how far you get into the gnome load sequence, you can also find useful information in `$HOME/.xsession-errors`

Comment: there is no such file.

Answer (score -1):

To find the GNOME logs on a Linux system, you can follow these steps:

1. Open the terminal: You can usually open the terminal by searching for "Terminal" in the applications menu or by using the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Alt+T.
2. Launch GNOME Logs: In the terminal, type the following command and press Enter:

   ```
   gnome-logs
   ```
3. GNOME Logs application: The GNOME Logs application should open, displaying system logs and other log categories such as Application Logs, Security Logs, and Hardware Logs.
4. Browse and search logs: You can browse through the different log categories by selecting them from the left sidebar. Within each category, you can scroll through the logs to review the information or use the search bar to search for specific log entries.

Please note that the availability and location of GNOME Logs may vary depending on your Linux distribution and GNOME version. If the "gnome-logs" command does not work, you can try alternative commands like "gnome-system-log" or "gnome-event-viewer" to access the logs.